# How to add more colors to calendar overlay in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2010 calendar overlay has a limitation of only 9 colors. Where as I need to have more colors as I have more than 9 views. How to add more colors and views to calendar overlay feature in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is a hard limit of 10 overlays in SharePoint.

```
public ICalendarAccessor CreateAccessor(string type)
{
    if (this.m_allIds.Count == 10)
    {
        throw new SPException(SPResource.GetString("CalendarAggregationLimit", new object[0]));
    }
    ICalendarAccessor accessor = this.CreateAccessor(type, Guid.NewGuid());
    this.m_allIds.Add(accessor.Id);
    this.m_accessorMap[accessor.Id] = accessor;
    return accessor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can have maximum of **ANY** 9 colors, you can customize it by CSS(not necessary to use the available ones), add it in page:

for LHS navigation:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-acal-color2{
BACKGROUND-COLOR: orange
}

.ms-acal-selcolor2{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #C0362C
}

.ms-acal-apanel-color2{
 BORDER-COLOR: #C3B7AC; BACKGROUND-COLOR: orange;
}
</style>
```

FOR calendar items:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-acal-item
{
  BACKGROUND-COLOR:#3B3C2B;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @Kanan, You have to add a script web part or modify the content of the page to change the colors defined by SharePoint. If you can add more colors you can't if you use the SharePoint calendar, change colors is the only thing you can do.

Comment: yes that is what i had mentioned "can have maximum of ANY 9 colors, you can customize it by CSS" . calendar allows maximum 9 colors, but what if anyone needs orange color, then my solution works, hope that helps.